Password Field in Custom Module (encrypt before save)
For a Custom Module which loads some data from NextCloud i need to store the credentials of the given user (only users with an account can access the calendar on NextCloud). There is no "real" API on the NextCloud side (afaik) - the data will be loaded via a cURL request, the credentials will be sent in plain as
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $usr . ":" . $pass);
...

So the module itself works but the module settings especially the password is stored in the database (in the module settings) as is (no hashing). From my point of view it is a bit risky to do that. Has anyone ever such a situation? How to handle it?
I think i "could" encrypt it via openssl_encrypt before save and decrypt if needed for the cURL request but is there a way to manipulate a form value (the password value) on PHP side before saving the module? If it would be a component I would know how to handle it in the table script but for a module and its params?
Tried something hardcoded:
class MyPasswordField extends TextField
{

    protected $type = 'myPassword';

    public function setup(\SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null): bool
    {
        $this->value = $this->decrypt($this->value);
        return parent::setup($element, $value, $group);
    }

    public function getInput(): string
    {
        $this->value = $this->decrypt($this->value);
        return parent::getInput();
    }

    public function setValue($value): void
    {
        $this->value = $this->encrypt($value);
    }


    private function decrypt($value)
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
    private function encrypt($value)
    {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

The idea was that it stores the hard coded string bar in the database but shows foo for testing the idea. Later on a Helper would be built to enncrypt / decrypt. But the setValue does not get called on save.

One potential way is to encrypt the value in the filter() method. Typically, you don't want the encrypted value to be filtered additionally anyways because that could lead to data corruption:
class MyPasswordField extends TextField
{
    public function setup(\SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null): bool
    {
        $value = $this->decrypt($value);

        return parent::setup($element, $value, $group);
    }

    public function filter($value, $group = null, ?Registry $input = null)
    {
        return $this->encrypt($value);
    }
}

